# get document title meta using javascript

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to implementing this simple script below, which would display the document title as assigned by wordpress (or an seo plugin) when the browser tab is in focus, and display an altrenate doc title when the tab is not in focus:

```
<script>
window.onblur = function () { document.title = 'Come Back!'; }
window.onfocus = function () { document.title = 'WP Doc Title'; }
</script>
```

how can i alter the above script to get the current tile?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`document.title` is both a getter and a setter. So you just need this

```
var title = document.title; // store the current title by accessing getter
console.log(title);
```

So access it outside event handler under a variable and then you could use it in `onfocus`

Answer (score 0):

Store it somewhere before you start changing it, and then use that for reverting back..

```
<script>
  var originalTitle = document.title;

  window.onblur = function () { document.title = 'Come Back!'; }
  window.onfocus = function () { document.title = originalTitle; }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onblur = function () { 
    document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML = 'Come Back!'; 
    alert(document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML);    
}
window.onfocus = function () { 
    document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML = 'WP Doc Title'; 
    alert(document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats about using some WP functions like the_title/get_the_title/bloginfo?
I just tried it out and it worked for me.

```
<script>
window.onblur = function () { document.title = 'Come Back!'; }
window.onfocus = function () { document.title = '<?php the_title(); ?>'
</script>
```

If it's not a single post try it with bloginfo('name'), would also work.
You can also get the title's tag content as a javascript variable. It would be the best way if you have a SEO plugin activated.

```
var title = document.title;
```

Could look like this:

```
<script>
var title = document.title;
window.onblur = function () { document.title = 'Come Back!'; }
window.onfocus = function () { document.title = title; }
</script>
```